# Error while using react native app in android or ios amulator/device

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

[This is the error I am getting while running my react native app on device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VS1n2.jpg)

I am unable to debug and resolve this error

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: on android/ios you can't display text without wrapper <Text>, try disabling components one by one to understand in which one it happens

Answer (score 0):

In react-native (unlike reactJS) you have to display all your text inside `<Text></Text>` component, like this:

```
<Text>your text goes here ...</Text>
```

So, you should check your app to find where there is text outside of this component and wrap it with `<Text></Text>`.